# Capture content after a word until condition Regex

Tags: regex

I have a transcript as follows

```
JOHNNY.
My name is John. People call me hello
Okay here it is

MR JOHNNY.
Hey Johjasa! My name is John Does

DOE.
My name is Doe not John Doe
```

In this case I want to capture the `My name is John. People call me hello Okay here it is`, and `Hey Johjasa! My name is John Doe`. Basically capture anything said by  JOHNNY or Mr.JOHNNY. NOTE: These conditions might come later as well, as in they can have more phrases as well.

I came up with this regex `(?<=JOHNNY\.).*` but this basically terminates at the newline, and doesn't actually capture the phrase.

Is this something which is achievable where I capture the string after `JOHNNY.` until i encounter (two new lines or an all upper case word),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use this:

```
(?<=JOHNNY\.\n)[\s\S]*?(?=\n\n|[A-F]+\.)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Lv2qX/1)